# CentOS 7 LaTex longtable incorrectly formated

Tags: longtable, overleaf, linux, centos

My longtable is formatted incorrectly in LaTex on CentOS 7.
For example, if I enter the code in overleaf, then the table is formatted correctly.
Is there a package from CentOS that formats the table correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: the operating system has essentially no effect on tex, what matters is what version of latex and the longtable package you have, about which you have given no information.

Comment: If you are using the texlive that comes as rpms with CentOS 7 it is really old (TeXLive 2012). There is much to gain by ignoring the rpms and install it yourself from texlive.org. 

If you don't want that it is possible whatever behaviour you have seen be different is only because of the longtable package *and* that a current longtable is possible to use in that old TeX environment (I don't know). If that is the case then you could instead just get that package from https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable and install it.